# Multiple <header> and <footer> in a HTML5 document

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

Is it fine to use multiple `<header>` and  in HTML 5, if yes then isn't semantically incorrect and won't it confuse mobile readers?

I saw many site uses like

```
<body class="home">
    <header class="hd1">
        <hgroup>
        <h1>HTML5 Documnet</h1>
        <h2>tagline</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header><!-- .hd1 -->
    <div class="main">
        <section class="hs1">
            <header>
            <h1>This is a Page Sub Title</h1>
            </header>
    
            <p>Some content...</p>
            <h2>Demonstrating EM and STRONG</h2>
            
            <p><strong>This text will have more importance (SEO-wise and contextually)</strong></p>         
            
            <footer>
            <p>Author: <cite>Louis Lazaris</cite></p>
            </footer>

        </section>
    </div><!-- .main -->
    <footer class="f1">
    <p>copyright &copy; year</p>
    </footer><!-- .f1 -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, multiple `<header>` and `<footer>` elements are fine. They aren't used the same as `<div id="header">` as most people use them for. Technically speaking, header and footer represent a header and footer of a section. A section being a piece of the page such as an article that contains header tags like `<h1>` and then content, then footer stuff like copyrights, citations, references, etc.

From the horses mouth:

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading
>   (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but this is not required. The
>   header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents,
>   a search form, or any relevant logos.

And

> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor
>   sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically
>   contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to
>   related documents, copyright data, and the like.

Directly from the spec at: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html

Note that as I said these are not used to create sections like people did with `<div id="header/footer">` it mentions this confusion in the spec:

> The footer element is not sectioning content; it doesn't introduce a
>   new section.

So, again, "technically" speaking, that *last* footer you have there introduces a new section and isn't semantic. From the spec's point of view anyways.