# HTML5: Multiple footers/headers in a section

Tags: html

I understand you can have multiple headers/footers in a page such as for the `<article>`s and another site wide header/footer for the `<body>` but I've not found anywhere stating that having multiple headers and or footers in a single section is acceptable.

```
<body>
<header class="header-group-1"></header>
<header class="header-group-2"></header>

<!-- other content -->

<footer class="footer-group-1></footer>
<footer class="footer-group-2></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you state the situation to use mutiple headers or footers for one "article" or "section"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple <header> and <footer> in a HTML5 document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499385/multiple-header-and-footer-in-a-html5-document)

Answer (score 6):

Multiple [`header` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.htmlhe-header-element) are allowed, and each of them specifies “introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element”, i.e. the nearest enclosing     article, aside, nav, section, blockquote, body, details, dialog, fieldset, figure, or td element. So you can have e.g.

```
<body>
<header>body header</header>
...
<article>
  <header>article header</header>
  ...
</article>
```

There is no prohibition against having e.g. two `header` elements (at the same level of nesting) in an `article` element. They would then both contain “introductory content” for it. It is however difficult to imagine situations where this would make sense, since `header` elements normally precede other content, and the `header` would thus be adjacent and could be combined into one.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can have multiple headers and footers in one section, W3C will validate for you, but its not recommended unless you have various articles within that section that require a header and footer per article. You may want to read up on this article:
http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

Comment: A `header` element specifies a header “for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element”, so if it is a child of a `section` element, it specifies a header for it, not for any inner element.