# Is it considered 'bad practice' to use multiple header tags?

Tags: html

Is using multiple `header` tags common practice when it comes to separating a main-header and a sub-header, or should you divide one header into two sections using `div`s?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header--main-header">
    </header>
    <header class="header--sub-header">
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

As opposed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="header--main-header">
        <!-- Main-Header Content -->
      </div>
      <div class="header--sub-header">
        <!-- Sub-Header Content -->
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would either of these methods be the "best-practice" way to achieve a website header and sub-header, or is there another approach that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, we can! See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658513/890357

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5: Multiple footers/headers in a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655804/html5-multiple-footers-headers-in-a-section)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use as many headers as you like. We tend to use a main header at the top of our HTML containing our `h1`, navigation, utilities etc. But headers can also be used for the head of a section.

For instance:

```
<header>
  <h1>The most important heading on this page</h1>
  <p>With some supplementary information</p>
</header>

<article>
  <header>
    <h2>Title of this article</h2>
    <p>By Richard Clark</p>
  </header>
  <p>...Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet...</p>
</article>
```

It is the `head` tag that should only be used once per page.

Comment: ^ This answer is correct. Its semantic html5 markup. Each section / article could also have a footer, these tags pair with the closest tag around them.

Answer (score 1):

The header tag element represents a container for introductory content or a set of navigational links.

A header tag element typically contains:

- one or more heading elements (h1 - h6)
- logo or icon
- authorship information

You can have several  elements in one document.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `header` tag, followed by the `nav` or `div` tag itself. It is best-practice to use the `nav` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Convention in HTML is that generally there is one header tag. Sub-headers can be seperated by any element you wish, `div` for example like you have.

You can check out some of the example usage of header [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_header.asp) and [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/).