# Can section have multiple headings?

Tags: html

Is it okay if i use multiple headings (h1-h6) inside one section?

```
<article>
 <header>
  <h2>....</h2>
  <p>../p>
 </header>
 <p>..</p>
 <section>
  <h3>....</h3> //first header
  <p>..</p>
  <h4>....</h4> //second header
  <p>..</p>
 </section>
</article>
```

W3C is saying that:

> The theme of each section should be identified, typically by including
>   a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5: Multiple footers/headers in a section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655804/html5-multiple-footers-headers-in-a-section)

Answer (score 0):

[From W3C;](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections)

> Sections may contain headings of any rank, and authors  are strongly
>   encouraged to use headings of the appropriate  rank for the section's
>   nesting level.

For example, the following is correct:

```
<body>
 <h4>Apples</h4>
 <p>Apples are fruit.</p>
 <section>
  <h2>Taste</h2>
  <p>They taste lovely.</p>
  <h6>Sweet</h6>
  <p>Red apples are sweeter than green ones.</p>
  <h1>Color</h1>
  <p>Apples come in various colors.</p>
 </section>
</body>
```

However, the same document would be more clearly expressed as:

```
<body>
 <h1>Apples</h1>
 <p>Apples are fruit.</p>
 <section>
  <h2>Taste</h2>
  <p>They taste lovely.</p>
  <section>
   <h3>Sweet</h3>
   <p>Red apples are sweeter than green ones.</p>
  </section>
 </section>
 <section>
  <h2>Color</h2>
  <p>Apples come in various colors.</p>
 </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that the examples come from an obsolete W3C recommendation. The current HTML recommendation is HTML 5.1, which has rewritten those examples, because the upper example is misleading for screen reader users.